# Upload SQL Database and its Data to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I created an SQL database using ASP.NET Core 1.1 Migrations.

After I created the database I added some data to the database.

- What options do I have to upload this database to Azure?
  I need to send the Scheme and the initial data.
- Is it possible to run Entity Framework migrations on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article describes the possibilities to migrate an existing database to SQL Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate

However, in your scenario, this might be overkill to go through the steps of realy doing a migration.

If your number of tables and data is rather small, why not create a SQL script to create the tables & insert the data?

Connect to your SQL Azure using SQL Server Management Studio and execute the script.

As for the Entity Framework, yes, you can run those on SQL Azure as well.